# Play Framework: Chain ActionsBuilder and ActionRefiner

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, actionbuilder

I am desperate. 
I tried to do ActionComposition like in the very last paragraph of the official docs: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition

My code:

```
object ActionBuilder1 extends ActionRefiner[Request, Request] {
  override protected def refine[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Either[Result, Request[A]]] = Future {Right(request)}
}


object ActionBuilder2 extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) : Future[Result] = {
    block(request)
  }
}
```

In my controller:

```
def yolo = ActionBuilder2 andThen ActionBuilder1 {
  Ok("ASd")
}
```

But the compiler says:

```
actions.ActionBuilder1.type does not take parameters
def yolo = ActionBuilder2 andThen ActionBuilder1 {
                                               ^
```

I really do not know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Scala can't work out what you mean by:

```
ActionBuilder2 andThen ActionBuilder1 { // Some block }
```

so the easiest way seems to be declaring that chain as a thing in its own right, *then* applying the block to it:

```
val actionChain = ActionBuilder2 andThen ActionBuilder1

def yolo = actionChain { 
  Ok("yolo")
}
```

**Verification** that it's working in the desired order (`2` then `1`), via logging:

```
object ActionBuilder1 extends ActionRefiner[Request, Request] {
  override protected def refine[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Either[Result, Request[A]]] = Future {
    Logger.info("ActionBuilder1")
    Right(request)
  } 
} 


object ActionBuilder2 extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) : Future[Result] = {
    Logger.info("ActionBuilder2")
    block(request)
  }
}
```

In the console upon requesting the endpoint:

```
[info] application - ActionBuilder2
[info] application - ActionBuilder1
```

Comment: You are totally right. I just forgot brackets around the actionChain